# can't redirect form on submit

Tags: php, forms, redirect, onsubmit

Ok - I know I am being an idiot but I can not seem to get this form to redirect as I want it to:

```
    <form id="post" method="post" action="" name="post" onSubmit="window.location='http://www.website.com/overview'" >
        <input type="hidden" name="terms-and-conditions" value="true">
        <p class="submit">
            <input id="agree" type="submit" value="I Agree" name="agree"> 
            <input type="button" value="I Disagree" onClick="window.location='http://www.website.com'">
        </p>
    </form>
```

When the button type is "submit" it won't redirect in my PHP page. I have a feeling I am missing something obvious...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do

```
<form id="post" method="post" action="http://www.website.com/overview" name="post">
```