# PHP Submit Redirect

Tags: php, forms, redirect, authentication, submit

I'm doing a form with a submit button, but the submit button just takes you to the same page, I would like it to redirect to a specific page. How would this be done?

```
<body><form action="login.php" method="POST" >
<table>
<tr>
<td>Username: </td><td><input type="text" name="username" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password: </td><td><input type="password" name="password" /></td>
</tr>

</table>
<input type="submit" value="Log In"/> &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<input type="button"   value="Register" onClick="location.href='register.php'" />
```

Comment: is login.php the page you want to send them to, or the page on which they log in?

Comment: Note that if you do this, the login info has to be processed on the page you're sending them to, not on the page they use to log in.

Comment: @octern: Not in case of a redirect.

Comment: @hakra True. I interpreted the question as being about changing the behavior where "the submit button takes you to the same page," not about having the user end up on a different page. But regardless of what the OP meant, processing the login info on a single page and then redirecting (which is what you suggested?) is probably a better way to go.

Comment: I know and I'd say the question is not well worded. So instead of assuming too much, it's normally better to ask the OP what was meant specifically. Also this is a candidate to close I'd say because I can not imagine that there ain't a similar question already on the site that has not yet been answered.

Comment: possible duplicate of [can't redirect form on submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852850/cant-redirect-form-on-submit)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php header('Location: WHATEVER.php'); ?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

This has been downvoted twice and upvoted three times... So... Let's think here people.  if you LOGIN you NEED to go to login.php to submit the data to PHP then have PHP send the to the desired page, NOT HTML or you NEVER login.

```
if($successful_login){
   header('Location: WHATEVER.php');
} else {
   // Then send them back to login.php because their login failed.

}
```

Comment: The OP asked how to make the form submit to a specific page, not how to do a generic redirect.

Comment: Though processing the login info and then redirecting may be a better idea.

Comment: I would think so... lol.  I mean how else do they login first. IE: On successful login Header():die();

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="DESIRED_PAGE.PHP" method="POST" >
```

You have to target the action attribute of the form to the page you want it sends your form.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code on Google Chrome and I was redirected to login.php without any problems. If this is your entire code, then you are missing a closing `</form>` tag which could probably be a reason for improper behavior when using a different browser.

Also verify that login.php isn't sending the client back to the page you posted.

Comment: OP is asking how to go to a different page, after a successful login.